# Adding a JavaScript object to .xml.config file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a .xml.config file and I need to add JS that will pass certain variables to an object.

```
<!-- BEGIN: GUARANTEE -->
<span id="imageSpan"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mysite.com/Web/Seal/gjs.aspx?SN=953625677"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window._GUARANTEE && _GUARANTEE.Loaded) {
_GUARANTEE.Hash = "ZlUp0GQc2wW0JHvn%2F6XdQ4TR3IxlFbVCS52UG%2Fl2g%2FnPc31yD9Vzcbnx3ZTbkCS6oeX9twjSsE1Jrb7hr8RWQw%3D%3D";
_GUARANTEE.Guarantee.order = '<xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/OrderNumber"/>';
_GUARANTEE.Guarantee.subtotal = '<xsl:value-of select="/root/Orders/Order/OrderSubtotal"/>';
_GUARANTEE.Guarantee.currency = '<xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/CurrencySetting"/>';
_GUARANTEE.Guarantee.email = '<xsl:value-of select="/root/Orders/Order/Email"/>';
_GUARANTEE.WriteGuarantee("JavaScript", "imageSpan");
}
</script>
<!-- END: GUARANTEE -->
```

I'm getting an error related to, I think, the & signs. I tried adding `<![CDATA[]]>` before the js code but still getting the error.

Am I supposed to escape everything but the `<xsl: value-of select="" />` tags?

If anyone could provide some guidance that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried adding `<![CDATA[]]>` before the js code, but that won't help anything.

The correct form would be to add `<![CDATA[` before the js code and `]]>` after.

Or, yes, escape the `&` signs. (And for completeness, also all `<` signs, and even all `>` signs, which may cause problems under some circumstances.)